# Structuring a BIG view with Thymeleaf and Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm about to generate a pdf report (roughly 20 slides long) in java using Spring MVC, Thymeleaf and Flying-saucer. I would like to be able to structure the code according to the different slides so that I can easily add and remove slides and not have all code for all slides in one chunk. In the end, after Spring MVC and Thymeleaf are done, I guess I will have a lot of XHTML and CSS ready to be sent to Flying-saucer for PDF generation.

I haven't worked that much with Spring MVC but my feeling is that you first do the controller stuff, e.g. get data, work with the data and then put necessary data on the Model so Thymeleaf can continue and render the view based on a template and the data on the Model.

How can I divide the code parts in java and Thymeleaf in a good modular way? Anyone have a good design to be inspired by or can point me somewhere on the web where I can find good information about this?

Comment: If you are displaying as part of the same page you should be able to make fragmented Thymeleaf views and just import them into one "master" view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I suggest to fragment Thymeleaf templates into three parts - master, slide and content templates. You can fill report content dynamically from Spring MVC controller or build it in static way just in Thymeleaf.

I providing skeleton templates structure as I think it's the best (all templates supposed to be on root template path). If you want to add slide you just create new template with content and insert new line to master template. If you want to remove slide you just delete appropriate line.

> Master template - index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <th:block th:include="slide :: slide" th:with="content=${'content1'}"></th:block>
        <th:block th:include="slide :: slide" th:with="content=${'content2'}"></th:block>
        <th:block th:remove="tag" th:include="slide :: slide" th:with="content=${'content3'}"></th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Slide template - slide.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
    <body th:fragment="slide">
        <div class="slide">
            <div th:replace="${content} :: content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Content template 1 - content1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <ul th:fragment="content">
            <li>Content 1</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Content template 2 - content2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <span th:fragment="content">Content 2</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Content template 3 - content3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
       <p th:fragment="content">
           Content 3
       </p>
    </body>
</html>
```